# Error while creating an action: Action must be plain object

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I get an error when calling the action. I transfer the object using dispatch, but in this example it does not work. Tell me what is the error and how to implement it correctly?

api.js

```
export const getTables = () => getReq('https://test.online/tests');
```

action.js

```
export const getTables = () => {defaultAction("GET_TEST", Api.getTables)();}
```

utils.js

```
export const defaultAction = (constant, api) => async () => {
    const result = await api();
    return (dispatch) => {
        return dispatch({type: constant, payload: result})
    };
};
```

method.js

```
export const getReq = (url) => {
    const promise = axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: url,
        credentials: 'include',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            Authorization: localStorage.getItem('token'),
        },
    });
    return promise.then((response) => response.data);
};
```

Comment: Added the part of the code you are interested in at the end

Answer (score 1):

Your `getTables` action creator is missing a `return` statement and returns `undefined`. Or just skip the `{}`

```js
export const getTables = () => defaultAction("GET_TEST", Api.getTables)()
```

Alternatively to the weird "build a function and then execute it immediately" pattern you have going on there, you could also just

```js
export const getTables = defaultAction("GET_TEST", Api.getTables)
```

which has the same effect.